# Get single value from query

Tags: php, mysql

When someone joins a group, i want the creator of the group to get an email. So I query the database for the group with that group name and get the email of the group creator.

```
sql = "SELECT `groupcreatoremail` FROM `userchurch_signup` WHERE `groupname` = '". $groupname . "' limit 1" ;
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$creator_email = "";
while ($fieldinfo=mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
    $creator_email = $fieldinfo->groupcreatoremail;
}
```

Based on testing I'm not getting anything even though if i run the SQL statement it works.

Comment: Your script has no code that outputs anything. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Do you know that `$result` and `$result2` are __different__ vars?

Comment: This looks like it is probably **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from

Comment: Yup, this is not the whole script, just the part where I'm trying to get the email. Don't worry about injection, I'm not posting the whole script.

Comment: Thank you for your concern though Quentin.

Comment: Looks like this isn't possible. I'm just going to have to break database rules and store the creator email in the join table I guess. Yay me!

Comment: Why are you mixing the object-oriented style and the extremely verbose procedural one? This code is highly inconsistent and could use some careful attention. As with everything in programming the details matter.

Comment: $fieldinfo['groupcreatoremail'] works. Thans for nuthin!

Comment: @DuckofDeath my way works too, thanks for not trying! :)

Answer (score -1):

Referenced [fetch_assoc](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) about this simple issue. I would use their suggested method. however if you want to know more about the way you selected research on the function you're using.

More info can be found here how to use this information   [mysqli_fetch_field](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_field.asp)

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "result: " . $row["groupcreatoremail"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: You'll note that that is the exact method I'm using.

Comment: nope i'm using fetch_assoc, you're using mysqli_fetch_field in your while statement

Comment: Also I would highly recommend using PHP::PDO for database connections. Learn how to bind parameters versus your string concats above for your query to avoid SQL Injections.

Comment: if you look to the bottom, the mysqli_fetch_field link, you'll see it returns attributes of the field but value is neither of the attributes.